# How is it possible to make a horizontal bar (fixed position, always at the top of screen) while its height is unknown?

Tags: html, css

I want a horizontal bar at the top of `HTML` page. It should always be at the top of the screen, So I made this:

```
<body>
   <div id="message_bar" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 1000;">
   </div>

   <div class="other_divs" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
   </div>
</body>
```

Now, this bar should not cover the rest of the body. If I knew the height of it, let's be 50px for example, I would do it by:

```
 <body style="padding-top: 50px;">
```

But unfortunately, the `height` of this message_bar is variable and unknown (It's contents are set dynamically at server-side).

Is there any way to solve this problem purely by `CSS`?

Thank you very much.

P.S.
This message_bar would display like menu bars in windows applications: they are always at the top, and they never cover the main body. In fact, `vertical scroll bar` starts from "other_divs".

UPDATE 2:

Hey, Unbelievable! I guess I've managed to create the potential layout for a horizontal menu bar, purely with `CSS`. Here is my solution thanks to the power of `vh`:

```
<body>
<div style="display:block; width:100%; height:95vh !important; overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="message_bar" style="float:left; width:100%; display:block;" >
        this text appears always on top
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100%; height:100%; display:block; overflow:auto;">
       <div id="main_content" style="background:blue;">
          Here lies the main content of the page. 
          <br />The below line is a set of 40 list items added to occupy space
         <ol><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li><li>i</li></ol>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I checked it in `Chrome`,`IE`, and `FireFox`, and it worked neatly!

Anyway, I must thank the community here; Even when no answer is provided, the discussion and different viewpoints stimulate thinking process and eases solution finding.

Comment: In fact, this message_bar should be `fixed` only when the vertical scroll bar is shown and the page is scrolled down.

Comment: I changed `overflow:scroll` to `overflow:auto` as Todd said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to solve this with purely CSS is adding a duplicate of the bar at the top of the page with `position: relative` and a lower z-index. This duplicate bar would always be hidden behind the fixed one (you could use `opacity: 0; pointer-events: none` if needed) and would push the rest of the page down. However this solution is very ugly as it adds a lot of HTML.

I recommend using JavaScript with jQuery for a pretty easy solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrapper').css('padding-top', $('.message_bar').outerHeight());
});
```

And create a wrapper div around the content of the page (`<div class="wrapper">Content...</div>`). Alternatively, you could apply the padding to the `body`.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting idea. but in my case, it may rise the size of the sended data.

Answer (score 2):

I am interested in your question, thanks for your information of the value of `vh` and `vw`. When I read your `UPDATE 2`. I found there is still something can be improved. The following is:

1. I change `overflow:scroll;` to `overflow:auto`. Because when your page haven't enough height. The value `overflow:scroll` will create a gray scroll bar. That is unfriendly for user.
2. I remove the most outer layer `<div style="display:block; width:100%; height:95vh !important; overflow:hidden;">...</div>` and retain the others. In other word, not to use `vh` also can be resolved your question.
3. There is my **[JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/2muap7zn/10/)** (*NOTICE*: the JSFIDDLE is not achieve the effect that the above following. **Copy these code on your native browser.** I think this reason is about virtual circumstance compatibility. It worked in chorme & Firefox & IE 10)

Comment: thanks for `overflow:auto`, It's also good but in my browser did not make any change. I had set `height=95vh`  to avoid that unnecessary scroll bar.. I also checked this code without the most outer layer, it didn't work. without it, the header(message_bar) will go with scrolling down.

Comment: Sorry, I checked again, `overflow:auto` is better. It removes inner scroll bar when it is unnecessary, as you mentioned. But `height:95vh` is still required to avoid another unnecessary scroll bar in the outer div.

Comment: @Ormoz `height:95vh' is actually useful. But you can remove the whole div which contain 'height: 95vh'. You can click [this link](http://toddmark.github.io/blog/test.html) to check it. The page's source code as same as my JSFIDDLE.

Comment: I tested it, It's fine but when you add some extra lines to the "message_bar", a second `vertical scroll bar` appears (belongs to the `body`).

Comment: @Ormoz You are right. But I haven't solution to fix it any more without javascript. I think using pure CSS to achieve the effect is a interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use relative positions? Remove `position: fixed;`. That's how it looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/darekkay/8ab6uw7n/1/

Edit: I don't think, you can achieve this with pure CSS, if you don't know the height of the message. But you can use jQuery:

```
$("#message_bar").show(function() {
    $( ".other_divs" ).css("margin-top", $(this).height() + "px");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/darekkay/8ab6uw7n/2/

Comment: If it is relative, when the height of the whole page exceeds the screen height, and the user scroll down the page, the message_bar would not be visible, while it should be always visible to the user.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer, but you probably won't be able to achieve this with CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class where are no scrollbars and then the position property will be `position:absolute;`
but if you want to keep this topHeader fixed in case of scrolling you have to use `.fixed` class

```
.topHeader {
    background:#345;
    color:#FFF;
    height:50px;
    padding:.5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    width:100%;
}
.fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

...and you some javascipt to bind scrol event:

```
var pixels= 50;  //in pixels

    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > pixels) {
            $('.topHeader ').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('.topHeader ').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Csdetesting Thanks, but I want to do it purely by CSS. I want the message_bar be always at the top of the screen, and the upper parts of the main body (the contents below message_bar) be accessible.